# the student's firstname, middlename,lastname are in different field in student personal info. I need to perform search operation by full name

Tags: php, mysql

```
select a.studentid, CONCAT(a.firstname,' ',a.middlename,' ',a.lastname) AS studentname, a.birthdate,b.admissiondate,b.status,c.facultyname,d.classname,e.sectionname
from studentpersonalinfo as a, studentacademicinfo as b, faculty as c, class as d, section as e 
WHERE a.studentid=b.studentid AND b.facultyid=c.facultyid AND b.classid=d.classid AND b.sectionid=e.sectionid AND b.status='running' and studentname LIKE '%$name%'  ORDER BY $sort $order limit $offset,$rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I replaced in your `WHERE Condition` the `studentname LIKE '%$name%'` with `CONCAT_WS(' ', a.firstname,a.middlename,a.lastname) LIKE '%$name%'`.

The General Syntax of CONCAT_WS is:

```
CONCAT_WS (separator, string1, string2,…)
```

now it should work:

```
SELECT a.studentid, CONCAT(a.firstname,' ',a.middlename,' ',a.lastname) AS studentname, a.birthdate, b.admissiondate, b.status, c.facultyname, d.classname, e.sectionname 
FROM studentpersonalinfo as a, studentacademicinfo as b, faculty as c, class as d, section as e 
WHERE a.studentid = b.studentid AND b.facultyid = c.facultyid AND b.classid = d.classid AND b.sectionid = e.sectionid AND b.status = 'running' and CONCAT_WS(' ', a.firstname, a.middlename, a.lastname) LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY $sort $order limit $offset, $rows
```

it's also possible to use it like you have done, just replace the `CONCAT` from `SELECT` to `CONCAT_WS(' ', a.firstname, a.middlename, a.lastname) AS studentname`

so in general your code should look:

```
    SELECT a.studentid, CONCAT_WS(' ', a.firstname, a.middlename, a.lastname) AS studentname, a.birthdate, b.admissiondate, b.status, c.facultyname, d.classname, e.sectionname 
    FROM studentpersonalinfo as a, studentacademicinfo as b, faculty as c, class as d, section as e 
    WHERE a.studentid = b.studentid AND b.facultyid = c.facultyid AND b.classid = d.classid AND b.sectionid = e.sectionid AND b.status = 'running' and studentname LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY $sort $order limit $offset, $rows
```

Now it should work properly...

for more information see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws